# Bash - If press Esc when taking user string-input from "read" command, stop and then do other action

Tags: bash, shell-script, escape-characters

How can i get this feature to work?

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> while taking inputs from the user will exit the script

```
read -r -p "Enter the filenames: " -a arr

if press Esc; then
     read $round
     mkdir $round
fi

for filenames in "${arr[@]}"; do
   if [[ -e "${filenames}" ]]; then
        echo "${filenames} file exists (no override)"
   else
        cp -n ~/Documents/library/normal.cpp "${filenames}"
   fi
done
```

How can i detect <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in this script?

PS: Saw many resources 
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-esc-key-in-a-case-statement-759927/ 
they **use another variable** like `$key` or `read -n1 $key` just **one character input**

but here **what will i do if I've a string or an array?**

Comment: Since you want to exit the script anyway when `Esc` is pressed, why not use the usual `Ctrl+C` to terminate the script? If there are reasons against it, please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: i just used an example.. Ok will clarify

Comment: Why do you want to prompt your users instead of just reading arguments from the command line? Prompting is hard, it means the script cannot be automated, it cannot be run again with the same arguments and it is very easy to make a typo if laboriously writing out the file names, while when passing them as arguments you can use tab-completion. So maybe you don't need this feature at all?

Comment: Above script is just a dummy one. With a healthy mind, i do need this feature

Comment: What keeps you from trying an adaption of your referred quote, like `while read Arg; do case $Arg in (*$'\e'*) echo Escape;; *) echo $Arg;;  esac; done`? Be aware that here the "return" key is needed to complete the `read`; an immediate reaction on `<ESC>` is not possible.

Comment: Please reconsider. Prompting users is the worst possible way of getting data. There simply is no benefit over running `script.sh /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3`. That is easier for you, easier for your user and just better for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I tweaked my script. Hope it helps.

This should work in **bash**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Bind the Escape key to run "escape_function" when pressed.
bind_escape () { bind -x '"\e": escape_function' 2> /dev/null; }

# Unbind the Escape key.
unbind_escape () { bind -r "\e" 2> /dev/null; }

escape_function () {

unbind_escape
echo "escape key pressed"
# command/s to be executed when the Escape key is pressed
exit

}

bind_escape

# Use read -e for this to work.
read -e -r -p "Enter the filenames: " -a arr

unbind_escape

# Commands to be executed when Enter is pressed.
for filenames in "${arr[@]}"; do
   if [[ -e "${filenames}" ]]; then
        echo "${filenames} file exists (no override)"
   else
        cp -n ~/Documents/library/normal.cpp "${filenames}"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to read the file paths from a file or pass them as arguments to the script, like [@terdon said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/708666/bash-if-press-esc-when-taking-user-string-input-from-read-command-stop-and/708819#comment1341589_708666)

The best way to exit `read` on an Escape key press seems to be: https://superuser.com/questions/1267984/how-to-exit-read-bash-builtin-by-pressing-the-esc-key/1447324#1447324

Another inferior way (it cannnot differentiate between Esc and arrow key presses):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


inputString=''

clear() { printf '\033c'; }

ask() {
    clear
    printf '%s' "Enter the filenames: $inputString"
}

ask

while :; do
    read -rN 1 char

    case "$char" in
        $'\e') # Esc (or arrow) key pressed
            clear
            exit
            ;;
        $'\n') # Enter key pressed
            break
            ;;
        $'\177') # Backspace key pressed
            [[ "${#inputString}" -gt 0 ]] &&
                inputString="${inputString::-1}"

            ask
            continue
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac

    [[ -n "$char" ]] &&
        inputString+="$char"
done


array_fromString() {
    local -n array_fromString_a="$1"

    local IFS=$'\n'
    array_fromString_a=(
        $(xargs -n1 <<< "$2")
    )
}


files=()
array_fromString files "$inputString"
echo "Entered filenames: "
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```